# Android 11 falhas ao compartilhar arquivo

Tags: java, android

Sempre compartilhei arquivos via meu app, porem com a versão do android 11 não consegui mais realizar este processo, pois o arquivo em questão não vai. Tentei utilizar FileProvide conforme a documentação porem retorno erro: (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Download/Teste2.txt). Já tentei de várias formas verificando várias sugestões e até momento não consegui e resolvi pedir ajuda.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<xml version=1.0 encoding=utf-8>
<manifest xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.login.projetobase">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:restoreNeedsApplication="true">


        <!-- android.support.v4.content.FileProvider  / androidx.core.content.FileProvider -->
         <provider
          android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
          android:authorities="com.login.projetobase.FileProvider"
          android:exported="false"
          android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
          <meta-data
              android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
              android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
          </provider>



        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- GRUPO STORAGE -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path
        name="Download"
        path="/" />
</paths>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String P_ACTIVITY = "MainActivity";
    util utl = new util();
    String ativa_log = "S";

    File sdcard_sdk29;
    private static java.io.File sdcard;


    Button btn ;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button)     findViewById(R.id.btn01);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
            public void onClick(View v) {
                utl.PRINT_LOG(1, P_ACTIVITY+"btn.setOnClickListener-> **** INICIOU ****", ativa_log);
                COMPARTILHA();

            }
        });

    }




    public void COMPARTILHA() {
        try {
            utl.PRINT_LOG(2, P_ACTIVITY + " COMPARTILHA() ...... INICIADO", ativa_log);

            String NOME_ARQ = "Teste2.txt";
            String texto = "Teste de compartilhamento";
            File arq;
            byte[] dados;


            String RAIZ3 = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();

            // CRIA O ARQUIVO NA PASTA DOWNLOAD
            arq = new File(RAIZ3 , NOME_ARQ);
            utl.PRINT_LOG(2, P_ACTIVITY + " COMPARTILHA()-> DIRETORIO  = ["+RAIZ3.toString()+"]", ativa_log);
            FileOutputStream fos;
            dados = texto.getBytes();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(arq);
            fos.write(dados);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

           //INICIANDO O PROCESSO DE COMPARTILHAR AQUIVO
            //Uri arquivo = Uri.fromFile(arq);
            //Uri arquivo2 = Uri.parse(arq.toString());

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.login.projetobase.FileProvider", arq);

            utl.PRINT_LOG(2, P_ACTIVITY + " COMPARTILHA2()-> CAMINHO URI = ["+contentUri.toString()+"]", ativa_log);
            utl.PRINT_LOG(2, P_ACTIVITY + " COMPARTILHA2()-> processando.....", ativa_log);


            final Intent _intent = new Intent();
            _intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            _intent.setType("application/pdf");
            _intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            _intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Compartilhamento com anexo");
            _intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Teste de Compartilhamento");
            _intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  contentUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(_intent, "Compartilhar"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            utl.PRINT_LOG(3, P_ACTIVITY + " ERRO->"+e, ativa_log);
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "ERRO="+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: No Android 11 não é possivel aceder ao armazenamento interno ou externo, apenas ao directorio de dados da app, para aceder ao armazenamento tem de usar Scoped Storage ou pode incluir a premissão: `android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` contudo esta premissão apenas é atribuida a apps que demonstrem necessidade e têm de ser autorizadas pela Google para serem publicadas na Play Store

Comment: Bom dia Tiago Oliveira, obrigado pela ajuda e dedicação do seu tempo em me ajudar! Eu fiz um ajuste no arquivo provider_paths.xml onde estava <Files-path para <external-path e funcionou o código acima. Porém também coloquei a permissão que falou em meu AndroidManisfest android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, permissão não sei informar ainda se o que fez funcionar foi a permissão ou ajuste que informar, então vou realizar mais alguns testes e informo aqui para ajudar outro pessoal que passe pela mesma dificuldade que passei aqui. Desde já agradeço atenção e tempo da ajuda

Comment: O Android é suposto bloquear qualquer path que não esteja em `"/data/user/0/app.package.name/"`, sem essa premissão não é suposto funcionar, se o objetivo for publicar na playstore, deve usar o Scoped Storage, uma vez que as revisões de apps (a esta data) esta suspensa, para obter um `input stream` ou `output stream` pode seguir a minha resposta nesta pergunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62899773/saving-binary-files-with-scoped-storage